# React and Bootstrap Modal Render after ajax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need it when I click the button, call an Ajax jquery and update a list (this.state.arrPizzas).
I tried to insert it into the componentDidMount function, but it doesn't update.
Basically when calling the getPizza function, you should update the value of arrPizzas, which is not the case today

```
class CardapioPizza extends Component {    


constructor(props) {
    super(props);        
    this.state = {
        arrPizzas: "Inicio"
    }

    this.getPizza = this.getPizza.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount CardapioPizza");       
}

getPizza(){         
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href + "/pizzas",
        type: "POST",
        data: { size: 7 }
    }).done(function(retorno){
        this.setState({
            arrPizzas: Math.random()
        });
        $("#mCardapioPizza").modal("show");
    });           
}


render() {
   
    
    return(
        <div id="mCardapioPizza" className="modal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="mCardapioPizza" aria-hidden="true">
            <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div className="modal-content bg-modal">
                    <div className="modal-header">
                        <h5 className="modal-title fw-700 font-30 color-white modal-title-centralizado">ESCOLHA SABORES DE PIZZA</h5>
                        <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-body" id="teste">    
                        { this.state.arrPizzas }
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer border-0">
                        <div className="row w-100">
                            <div className="col-12 p-0">
                                <button type="submit" className={"btn btn-primary btn-lg col-12" }>
                                    <i className="icon-check"></i> ENTRAR
                                </button>    
                            </div>
                        </div>                            
                    </div>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       )       
   }
}

export default CardapioPizza;
```

Comment: you're in react... why don't you try `axios` or `fetch` instead of `$.ajax`

Comment: because i have a legacy code in jquery. Jquery ajax is priority in this project.

Comment: What error do you see in the console? Maybe you see "`this.setState` is not a function"?

Comment: After render on first time, not update more... Var this.state.arrPizzas not update...

Comment: While that doesn't answer my question, could you also add where you're calling the `getPizza` function currently?

Comment: Another react component class. Basicaly button click call getPizza. Function getPizza need update this.state.arrPizzas  and update a modal body...

Comment: Mixing Bootstrap and React usually requires some integration whenever jquery would normally be required. Use React-bootstrap (for Bootstrap 3.x) or reactstrap for 4.x.  Here's an [example page](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/) showing how reactstrap provides various bootstrap modals as React components.